# Difference between time complexity and computational complexity

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory

For measuring the complexity of an algorithm, is it time complexity, or computational complexity? What is the difference between them?
I used to calculate the maximum (worst) count of basic (most costing) operation in the algorithm.

Comment: Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted. If you don't get a satisfying answer after a week or so, feel free to flag for migration.

Comment: @D. W. I will respect that next time :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Computational complexity is the general subject of using complexity measures to compare programs or algorithms. Time complexity and space complexity are two measures that are commonly used when talking about computational complexity, but there are others.

For example, it's common to look at the number of comparisons performed in a sorting algorithm.

Comment: You haven't used the term `various other resources`which are helpful in computation! So, a downvote. Please visit my answer. It is not used as a key factor to compare algorithms, it's for the whole program and the resources used to perform those computation, like memory,parallel threads,etc.

Comment: @shekharsuman Sorry, but I find both your comment and your answer hard to understand.

Comment: @Anonymous- I am really sorry that you couldn't get my point,but,please go through the Wikipedia link that I have referred in my answer! Really sorry not to make you understand.

Comment: @shekharsuman Anonymous hasn´t used the term `various other resources`, but you too didn´t. If that is a downvote reason, I´ll give you mine. And no, time/space complexity is not for a whole program with GUI interaction etc., only for algorithms, and has nothing to do with technical stuff like multiple threads (while the ability to parallelilze is an important aspect for algo´s too, it´s not expressed in complexities)

Comment: @deviantfan-So what else have I mentioned in my answer. It seems youare reading some third answer which hasn't been posted. Please don't mind,but, don't you see those bold-code based `Time-Complexity : Algorithm :: Resources(computer-based) : Computational Complexity.` in my answer. I don't know what else should've I marked on and this is the reason why I downvoted this answer of Anonymous! Please justify your point SIR.

Comment: @shekharsuman More reasons? I don´t understand this particular line at all, and why it is mathematical with it´s : and :: . The wikipedia quote is unnecessary  and `time complexity [is] to identify the complexity of execution of algorithm` doesn´t answer anything because it clear to everyone, and the rest of the sentence makes it sound like time and computational compl. are completely different things

Comment: @deviantfan-Well, that's the question of OP, and yes,they both aren't the same. Time-complexity is just a minor segment at all, I again request you to go through the link! Also, what else could I have added better! And, it seems you aren't kinda mathematical guy enough to understand those ratio & proportions,PARDON ME FOR THIS!

Comment: @shekharsuman a) Calm down, it´s pointless to argue. b) I don´t see a ratio (like % numbers) anywhere and it wouldn´t make sense; same for proportions. c) Thanks, but I know what complexity means without Wikipedia. d) The link to Wikipedia doesn´t make your answer good.

Comment: Well, for (C)then you are considering complexity & computational complexity the same,means you are underestimating the power/role of computer!For (a) Thanks, but,I am consistently trying to do the same. (B)  Yes,it makes sense logically,need to check your logic out in conceptual things. (D) Yes,at least it gives more clarification about my/anyone's answer! NOw, I further don't want to argue, I will just post this as a meta question,better it be dragged down to the court of justice! Thanks anyway for your MUCH-VALUED opinion. @deviantfan

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76750/discussion-between-deviantfan-and-shekhar-suman).

Comment: Finally you won Anonymous & @deviantfan. Thanks for making me understand my mistake.